# what is the "user" in datadog

Tags: go, datadog

I am little embarrased, as this is probably very banal, but it's really not making any sense to me.

I have a little golang web-application, that I for now am just localhosting.

I have some logging with logrus going on in the project, and want to use datadog to get a nice and visual dashboard for my application.

So I follow a bunch of the steps on their page, download their dockerimage and run it, and i am able to see some data!

I then follow the instructions further on, under a headline called "docker integration".
here I am asked to run the following command:

```
 usermod -a -G docker dd-agent
```

To which the response "cannot find user "dd-agent"" is given. But what is this "user" value?
Is it the user to which I have signed up to datadog with? something else?
I find it very unspecified?
would very much appreciate a helping hand

Comment: oh, do you think I could set it to the username that I use to log into my machine with?

Comment: The `dd-agent` ([**D**atadog **D**ocker **Agent**](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/docker/?tab=standard)) user is automatically created by the relevant [Dockerfile](https://github.com/DataDog/datadog-agent/blob/master/Dockerfiles/agent/amd64/Dockerfile#L138). You need to make sure that whatever step-by-step guide you're following you do not omit a step and also do not introduce a new step, from a different guide... there's quite a lot of them [there](https://docs.datadoghq.com/getting_started/), don't mix them up.